# Does leaving on nut locks hurt strings?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I just got a guitar with a Floyd-Rose bridge, complete with a nut built for nut locks.

Should I leave the nut locks on until I need to change strings, or possibly need to retune with the knobs?

Or should I take them off whenever I know I'm not going to play for a while?

Answer (score 2):

Let sleeping dogs lie. Or leave the nut locks alone. They won't do any damage, only release them when it's string change time.